# Azure WebRole + Flask: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wsgi_app'

Tags: azure, iis, flask, azure-web-roles

Unlike
[Azure Flask Deployment - WSGI Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32518358/361100) problem, deploying Flask app to Azure Web Role throws a following problem.

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wsgi_app'

What is this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it finally.

The startup `.py` file has to define `wsgi_app` after the Flask app definition.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# define for IIS module registration.
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And also, `{StartupModule}.wsgi_app` is defined in `Project properties >  Web > WSGI Handler`.

To shorten trial-and-error time, it would be good to start with newly created Azure WebRole Python project template.

Whooa. spent a whole day.